# WP Custom Taxonomy Query

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Custom Post Type ( post type- portfolio , taxonomy - portfolio-type )

```
Parent Category 1
    Sub Category 1
        Product One
        Product Two
    Sub Category 2
        Product One
        Product Two
    Sub Category 3
        Product One
        Product Two

Parent Category 2
    Sub Category 1
        Product One
        Product Two
    Sub Category 2
        Product One
        Product Two
    Sub Category 3
        Product One
        Product Two
```

What will be the good practice for the following :

( Assume as post type- portfolio , taxonomy - portfolio-type )

1. To create a category page where all products will show under each category
2. To show only category name with link and its thumb , when user click on that then they will get sub category and after clicking any of sub category they will see product with link and thumb.
3. Only to get all category including child or sub category.
4. Query by category or subcategory and then show its product.

Comment: its already builtin system on woocommerce . You can set it through woocommerce setting product view. there set category instead of product for shop page.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a screenshot hope this will help you.

```
Woocommerce > Settings> Products> Display
```

[image]

Comment: I am talking about custom post not related to woo-commerce. And also there will be query code not any visual configuration :) . Thanks for your reply